# How to draw a arc in a surface

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

i want to draw a semicircle inside a surface. So i thought to use
`pygame.draw.arc()`  but i cant figure out how to draw the arc inside of a surface i have seen the [official_docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.arc) and am using `math.radians()` to convert degrees to radians but i cant see the arc. A circle is being drawn tho...

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

surf = pygame.Surface((100, 100))
surf.fill("green")
rect = surf.get_rect(center=(100, 100))

run = 1
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = 0

    screen.fill((255, 202, 135))
    pygame.draw.circle(surf, (255, 255, 255), (30,30),25)
    pygame.draw.arc(surf, (255, 255, 255), rect, math.radians(270), math.radians(90))
    screen.blit(surf, rect)

    pygame.display.flip()
pygame.quit()
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The position of the circle segment must of course be relative to the `Surface` on which the circle segment is drawn and not the absolute position on which the `Surface` is then placed on the screen:

<s>`pygame.draw.arc(surf, (255, 255, 255), rect, math.radians(270), math.radians(90))`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.arc(surf, (255, 255, 255), (0, 0, 100, 100), math.radians(270), math.radians(90))
```